# how to combine JDBI @GetGeneratedKeys with Mapper

Tags: jdbi

I'd like JDBI to convert autogenerated primary key (Long value) to another class.

My DAO:

```
@RegisterMapper(SystemIdMapper.class)
public interface SystemDao {
  @SqlUpdate("insert into systems(device_id, user_id) values(:deviceId.value, :userId.value)")
  @GetGeneratedKeys
  @Mapper(SystemIdMapper.class)
  SystemId insert(@BindBean("deviceId") DeviceId deviceId, @BindBean("userId") UserId userId);
```

}

My mapper:

```
public class SystemIdMapper implements ResultSetMapper<SystemId> {
  @Override
  public SystemId map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) {
    return new SystemId(0L); //fake mapping to simplify example
  }
}
```

When I run my code I got NullPointerException in FigureItOutResultSetMapper.map(..) because

```
f = factory.mapperFor(rt, ctx);
```

set f to null. So my guess is that my mapper is incorrectly registered.

Except of using @RegisterMapper and @Mapper(SystemIdMapper.class) annotations I've also tried:

```
dbi.registerMapper(new SystemIdMapper());
```

but still with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify mapper in GetGeneratedKeys annotation.

```
@GetGeneratedKeys(SystemIdMapper.class)
```

@Mapper or @RegisterMapper is not used for getting the id back. It is used only during selecting values from table.